# infotemplate getting cutoff on top or bottom of screen?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, html, infowindow

in my app, i display few points across the map. these points have infotemplate with details in them and sometimes are quite large (around 350px height) if they have alot of information associated with it. so sometimes on smaller resolutions, either header or footer gets cutoff. is there any way to avoid this?

i am not setting up my anchors, just leaving it up to the arcgis javascript api.

map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));

Comment: ping: having the same problem. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem in one of our applications and were able to reduce the problem by putting all of our content inside a div with css height, width and overflow settings applied to make the content a consistent size.

In the script before you show the infoWindow, set the infoWindow size to a height and width that can contain the div. This will take some trial and error to handle the various browsers and resolutions your users will have.

I also found that setting the infoWindow size before AND after showing it helps to prevent the infoWindow from displaying partially off the map.

As I said, this reduce our sizing problems, but it was only when we switched to using the popup dijit that the sizing issue went away completely.